# Simple code for enumerating attributes and their values for each element [XML]

Tags: xml

I am a total beginner in JS/XML.

I have this simple code that needs to be extended to list on the screen attributes and their values for each element of a XML file.

```
      function printElement(indent, node) 
      {
         var i;
         if (node.nodeType == 3) 
          {
              document.write("<br />" +indent + node.nodeValue);
          }
         else 
          {  document.write("<br />" +indent + "[" + node.nodeName + "]");
             for (i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) 
               {
                  printElement(indent+tab, node.childNodes[i]);
               }
             document.write("<br />" +indent + "[/" + node.nodeName + "]");
          }
      }
```

I think I am supposed to use node.attributes but I don't know exactly how.
I don't know attribute's name.

This also doesn't work:

```
document.write("<br />" +indent + node.attributes[0].nodeValue);
```

The browser says "Object required" if (node.nodeType == 3).
If (node.nodeType == 2) the code lists something but not the attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < element.attributes.length; i++)
{
   var att = element.attributes[i];
   document.write(att.nodeName) + "=" + att.nodeValue + "<br/>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
node.attributes.getNamedItem("id").nodeValue
```

Where id is the attribute name.

Or

```
node.attributes[0].nodeValue
```

Comment: Hi Phil. 
For (node.nodeType == 2) the code lists something but not the attributes.

Comment: > Where id is the attribute name
Also, I don't know the name of the attribute - it can vary.